# Does RDLC fire any events when binding to a datasource?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc, rdl

In Microsoft ReportViewer Web server control I have a report in RDLC that "binds" a table to a datasource. Are there any events fired that I can hook into on each cell/row so that I can programmatically set formatting properties for each row/cell in my c# code?

Comment: rdlc is a file type don't fire events, which control/library you use for render reports?

Comment: Microsoft ReportViewer Web server control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Use an "expression" to set formatting.

- *How to: Add an Expression (Reporting Services)* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157376.aspx
- *Expression Dialog Box (Visual Studio Report Designer)* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661676.aspx
- *Working with Report Expressions* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx